# Source Code not working when uploaded to webserver?

Tags: php, svn, .htaccess

The site was working properly but after I modified a code file. the site stopped working. I have checked the error log and also tried other debugging solution but the site does not work at all. It shows a blank page. The error log displays nothing. The directory index is set to index.php. Please help me.[Note: the error reporting is turned on, Also its a plain php code file, When I echo something it does not display anything.]

```
<?php
  include_once('../../includes/SiteSetting.php');
  include_once('../../includes/classes/class.forum.php');

  $forumObj = new Forum();

  #--------GEtting Forum List-------------
  $categories = $forumObj->getCategories();
  if(!empty($categories) && count($categories)>0)
  {
    $i=0;
    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
      $forums = $forumObj->getForums($_GET['search'], $category['categoryid']);
      $ForumArray[$i] =  $category;
      $ForumArray[$i]['forums'] = $forums;
      $i++;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $ForumArray[$i]['forums'] ="";
  }
  $smarty->assign("forumarray", $ForumArray);
?>
```

Here is the htaccess
    Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This question was close recently so I had to add it again

Comment: sounds much more like an issue with the server configuration than the script itself.

Comment: what is the difference between the modified and unmodified code?

Comment: I just change the statement in else scope to  $ForumArray[$i]['forums'] ="";

Comment: Try putting an echo after the first `<?php` call and cutting out everything after it to make sure you see what you're supposed to. Then start adding in the code line-by-line to see where the problem lies. Might also help to have `error_reporting(-1);` at the top there too.

Comment: @LeonardChallis : I did that as well but the page still shows blank. I had added echo "Stephen"; after <?php

Comment: Did you cut out everything after the echo - so the whole page was just:
`<?php`
`error_reporting(-1);`
`echo 'Stephen';`

Comment: yes I did. let me try creating a new file with the same name and put the code in new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you see in error log? if you cannot figure out then check if other pages are working properly. You can also try to create a new file with the same code and delete the existing file.

Comment: error log shows nothing. I am trying to create a new file. Other pages seems to be working fine.

Comment: seem like the file was corrupted. Now its working fine after replacing the file.Thank you

Comment: Always take care of such issue. If you are not able to track the issue then try to replace the file.